# How to simplify the sum over 1/i?

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation, discrete-mathematics

With the recurrence relation:
$$ T(n) = 2T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + \frac{n}{\log(n)}$$

The "sum for all levels" in the recurrence tree is:
     $$ \sum_{i=0}^{\log n -1} \frac{n}{\log n - i} =  \sum_{i=1}^{\log n} \frac{n}{i} = n \sum_{i=1}^{\log n} \frac{1}{i}$$

Inside the analysis of the recurrence, $\sum 1/i$ appears and then bounded by $\Theta(\log\log n)$. Why is this?

Answer (score 5):

If you consider the last term in general,  $\sum_{[1\leq i \leq \log n -1]} \frac{1}{i} $ as
$$ \sum_{[1\leq i\leq k]} \frac{1}{i} $$
In this way, you can establish a bound using a integral generalization for this sum:
$$ \sum_{[1\leq i\leq k]} \frac{1}{i} \leq \int_{0}^{k} \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln (x)|_{0}^{k}= \ln(k) - \ln(1) = \ln(k)$$
But, in your problem, as we know, $k = \log n - 1$, so for above:

$$\sum_{[0\leq i \leq \log n -1]} \frac{1}{i} \leq \ln (\log n - 1)\leq \ln \log n$$

For that, $$\sum_{[0\leq i \leq \log n -1]} \frac{1}{i} = O(\ln\log n)$$

But, you can exhibit a constants to achieve, $\Theta(\log\log n)$.

Comment: Up to constants you may choose logarithm base 2. But when computing the primitive of $x^{-1}$ then the exact answer is $\ln(x)$, the natural logarithm, base $e$.

Comment: You're right,to fix, how is this in latex?

Answer (score 4):

$\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{i}$ is the $k$th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), which is $\Theta(\log k)$.

Comment: I like the simplicity and elegance of your argument, definitely. But, may be it's better a explicit proof for convince.

Comment: @d555 It's a standard fact and, hey, you've already included most of the proof in your answer. ($\sum_{x=2}^k\frac1x<\int_1^{k+1}\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x<\sum_{x=1}^k\frac1x$, the integral is equal to $\log(k+1)$ so $H_k-1<\log(k+1)<H_k$, so $\log(k+1)<H_k<\log(k+1)+1$.)

Comment: Ahh 0k, standard fact. Sorry.